# Can you use multiple wildcards in the VBA Dir function?

Tags: vba, excel, directory, wildcard

I am working on a macro to output filenames. I have a directory containing log files for an industrial batch process. Each batch is assigned a 5-digit batch number, and for each batch there is a .csv and .txt file. The filename for both files is the same and contains the batch number, for example:

```
XYZ 53482 20180827.csv
XYZ 53482 20180827.txt
XYZ 53483 20180828.csv
XYZ 53483 20180828.txt
XYZ 53484 20180829.csv
XYZ 53484 20180829.txt
```

My macro so far is:

```
Sub FindBatchFile()
Dim Batch As Double
Dim DirPath As String, r As Integer

Batch = InputBox("Enter Batch Number")

DirPath = Dir("C:\Data\* " & Batch & "*", vbDirectory)
r = 1
Workbooks.Add
MsgBox (DirPath)

Do Until DirPath = ""
Cells(r, 1).Value = DirPath
MsgBox (DirPath)
r = r + 1
DirPath = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

This works adequately but the output contains both .csv and .txt files. Is there a way of using multiple wildcards in the Dir function (ie. include a "`*.csv`" criterion as well as the "`*Batch*`")?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How about `DirPath = Dir("C:\Data\* " & Batch & "*.csv", vbDirectory)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will work as you expect it to, just added the `.csv` in your DirPath:

```
Sub FindBatchFile()
Dim Batch As Double
Dim DirPath As String, r As Integer

Batch = InputBox("Enter Batch Number")

DirPath = Dir("C:\Data\* " & Batch & "*.csv", vbDirectory)
r = 1
Workbooks.Add
MsgBox (DirPath)

Do Until DirPath = ""
    Cells(r, 1).Value = DirPath
    MsgBox (DirPath)
    r = r + 1
    DirPath = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks Xabier! Such a simple solution but it works perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to reply